# Change state of modal widget outside its class in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

I have two different files: `HomeScreen.js` and `ModalWidget.js`. The second file contains implementation of modal dialog window and I need to call this widget by clicking the button on home screen. Also this modal must have an ability to close itself with button on it. I tried to use global state hook, but it gave me an error message: `Invariant Violation: Invalid Hook call`. So, how can I call this modal from the home screen?

**ModalWidget.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, Button, Modal } from 'react-native';

export function ModalWidget(modalState) {

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(modalState);

  return (
    <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
      >
      <Button
        title="Close"
        onPress={setModalVisible(false)}
      />
    </Modal>

  )
};
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { ModalWidget } from '../components/ModalWidget';

export default function HomeScreen() {

  const [modalState, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ModalWidget
        state={modalState}
      />
      <Button
        title="Open"
        onPress={setModalVisible(true)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass a function as a prop and also it in HomeScreen.
HomeScreen.js

```js
<ModalWidget
  state={modalState}
  onPress={closeModel}
/>

closeModel(){
  setModalVisible(true)
}
```

ModalWidget.js

```js
<Modal
  animationType="slide"
  transparent={true}
  visible={modalVisible}
>
  <Button
    title="Close"
    onPress={props.onPress()}
  />
</Modal>
```

Also, You can't access state in the function component.